# How to connect to MySql in Wakanda 2?

Tags: wakanda

In Wakanda 1.1 I used "model.mergeSQLCatalog()" to see the MySql db that I was wanting to work with, as per the documentation.  Trying to do the same in Wakanda 2, it tells me that that model.mergeSQLCatalog() is not a function.  I get the feeling that I am missing something really obvious, but for the life of me I can't see what it is.  Can someone enlighten me please?  (I am working with a trial license)

Answer (score 2):

`model.mergeSQLCatalog()` is deprecated since `v2.0.0`.
To keep working, add a SQL model:

- Right click on `models` folder > `new` > `model`
- Select `MySQL`
- Set your SQL server config

A new model folder is created where you can put your old `model.js` file.

Here some official doc that can help you : https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-data-external

Comment: Many thanks! Blindingly obvious once I got pointed that direction.